# Can't Center my text Logo in CSS and HTML

Tags: css, css-position

[live demo on Codepen here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EaZroz)

I can't determine my error and have searched but have just begun learning.

```
nav {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 0;
    margin: 20px 0 0;
}

nav il {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 10px;
    padding 0;
}

nav li {
    display: inline-block;
}

nav a {
    font-weight: 800;
    padding: 15px 10px;
}
```

Comment: It looks centered to me

Comment: Hey, The Joshua Jones dosen't seem to be aligned with the about in the NAV

Comment: What is it that you are targeting with nav il?  I've never heard of il before.. You may have meant li

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's that your unordered list in your nav isn't center. It has a left padding value. You can correct it with

```
nav ul {padding: 0;}
```

or more specifically

```
#logo + nav ul {padding: 0;}
```

or you can also do

```
header nav ul {padding: 0;}
```

Lastly, you don't have to set all padding to `0`.  You can also just use `padding-left: 0;` for any of the different style rules listed above.

All of that is preference.  Basically it's the unordered list's padding that is causing the issue.

Comment: Thanks Joseph! I don't know if I'm trying something wrong but, I still can't seem to get it aligned right.